# Android Studio monitor wont stop

Tags: android

I open my android studio and the messages in the android monitor are just not stopping. Following is a snapshot of what keeps appearing.

> 11-09 12:35:20.310 1583-22910/? D/UnityAdsDelegate: Ad is ready 11-09
>   12:35:20.710 757-1905/? D/GpsLocationProvider:
>   AGPS_RIL_REQUEST_SETID_IMSI 11-09 12:35:20.720 757-1905/?
>   D/GpsLocationProvider: phone.getCurrentPhoneType: 1 11-09 12:35:20.830
>   31669-31695/? D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes 11-09 12:35:20.830
>   31669-31695/? D/ScanRecord: first manudata for manu ID 11-09
>   12:35:20.830 31669-31695/? D/BtGatt.GattService: result:
>   ScanResult{mDevice=F4:F5:D8:82:0C:4B, mScanRecord=ScanRecord
>   [mAdvertiseFlags=-1,
>   mServiceUuids=[0000fe9f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb],
>   mManufacturerSpecificData={224=[0, 100, -54, -127, 6, 37]},
>   mServiceData={0000fe9f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648,
>   mDeviceName=null], mRssi=-38, mTimestampNanos=465816184502928} 11-09
>   12:35:20.830 31669-31695/? D/BtGatt.GattService: filter:
>   BluetoothLeScanFilter [mDeviceName=null, mDeviceAddress=null,
>   mUuid=null, mUuidMask=null,
>   mServiceDataUuid=0000fe2c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
>   mServiceData=[], mServiceDataMask=null, mManufacturerId=-1,
>   mManufacturerData=null, mManufacturerDataMask=null] 11-09 12:35:21.591
>   31669-31695/? D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes 11-09 12:35:21.591
>   31669-31695/? D/ScanRecord: first manudata for manu ID 11-09
>   12:35:21.591 31669-31695/? D/BtGatt.GattService: result:
>   ScanResult{mDevice=F4:F5:D8:82:0C:4B, mScanRecord=ScanRecord
>   [mAdvertiseFlags=-1,
>   mServiceUuids=[0000fe9f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb],
>   mManufacturerSpecificData={224=[0, 100, -54, -127, 6, 37]},
>   mServiceData={0000fe9f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648,
>   mDeviceName=null], mRssi=-38, mTimestampNanos=465816953210203} 11-09
>   12:35:21.591 31669-31695/? D/BtGatt.GattService: filter:
>   BluetoothLeScanFilter [mDeviceName=null, mDeviceAddress=null,
>   mUuid=null, mUuidMask=null,
>   mServiceDataUuid=0000fe2c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
>   mServiceData=[], mServiceDataMask=null, mManufacturerId=-1,
>   mManufacturerData=null, mManufacturerDataMask=null] 11-09 12:35:21.681
>   173-226/? D/WCND: is_cp2_alive_ok: open polling interface:
>   /proc/mdbg/loopcheck, fd = 14 11-09 12:35:22.092 173-226/? D/WCND:
>   is_cp2_alive_ok: loop: /proc/mdbg/loopcheck is OK 11-09 12:35:22.372
>   31669-31695/? D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes 11-09 12:35:22.372
>   31669-31695/? D/ScanRecord: first manudata for manu ID

PS: I have tried cleaning project and exiting the studio many times.I have also updated android studio to latest.

Comment: Have used 3.0 stable version ?

Comment: @Jyoti: Can you please share the tab(view) of AS under which you see these logs?

Comment: how to do that Manmeet...pardon my ignorance

Comment: it ended with following   15:40 ADB rejected shell command (cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats | grep 10129): closed

15:40 ADB rejected shell command (cat /proc/29209/stat): closed

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of system stuff is going on always.. try setting a filter. For example you could filter by package name: com.company.app

[image]

Comment: it is not even.  stopping even after i run my app. I am using 2.3.3

Comment: Did you do what I suggested? Put some random string in the package name field and click ok - logcat should now be empty..?

Comment: yea it gets empty but the problem seems deeper the monitor is stuck in  a loop its not showing my debug messages

Comment: Well of course it won't show your debug messages now that you set a random filter - that was just a test. If you set filter to your (correct) package name it should show messages from your application..

Comment: well i meant if i filter it with my message its not shoeing which means program is not running